# Pass variable to child widget FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, variables, flutter-listview

I've got Container with ListView Builder with child widget placed in separated file.

```
itemCount: articles.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index ) => allRadioList(articles[index], context),
```

My child widget:

```
Widget allRadioList(Article article, BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
      child: ListTile(
    title: Text(article.title),
    subtitle: Text(STRING VARIABLE),
    leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${article.urlToImage}")),
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined),
      tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10',
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ));
```

How can i pass IE STRING VARIABLE in child allRadioList widget from parent?

Comment: Aren't `articles[index]` & `context` already two variables that you pass to your child widget (`allRadioList` being the child widget). Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a new parameter to your `builder` function:

```
Widget allRadioList(
  Article article, 
  BuildContext context,
  String text, // <-- New variable
) {
  return <...>;
}
```

2. Pass the variable to the builder:

```
final text = 'Test';

<...>

itemCount: articles.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index ) => allRadioList(
  articles[index],
  context,
  text, // <-- Pass variable
),
```

3. Use the passed value in the code:

```
Widget allRadioList(
  Article article, 
  BuildContext context,
  String text,
) {
  return Card(
      child: ListTile(
    title: Text(article.title),
    subtitle: Text(text), // <-- Use the passed value
    leading: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/${article.urlToImage}")),
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.star_border_outlined),
      tooltip: 'Increase volume by 10',
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  ));
```

Comment: Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 3 found. For: itemBuilder: (context, index ) => allRadioList(
  articles[index],
  context,
  text, // <-- Pass variable
),

Comment: Have you extended the `allRadioList` function as I mentioned in step 1?

Comment: Yes. My code is: itemBuilder: (context, index ) => allRadioList(articles[index], context, text), and Widget allRadioList(Article article, BuildContext context, String text) {...}

Comment: After cleaning it works. My mistake, Thank you @mkobuolys